# match arms have incompatible types expected when reusing function inside match

Tags: rust

I get the below error when adding a second match condition

> `match` arms have incompatible types
>
> |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types

```
use std::io;

fn add(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    let total = x1 + x2;
    println!("Total is: {}", total);
    return total;
}
fn subtract(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    let total = x1 - x2;
    println!("Total is: {}", total);
    return total;
}
fn multiply(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    let total = x1 * x2;
    println!("Total is: {}", total);
    return total
}
fn divide(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
     let total = x1 / x2;
    println!("Total is: {}", total);
    return total
}

fn calc(operation: fn(num1: i32, num2: i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    let mut input_number = String::new();
    println!("Enter Number:");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_number)
        .expect("Not a valid string");

    println!("Enter another number:");
    let mut input_number2 = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_number2)
        .expect("Not a valid string");

    let parsed_numb1: i32 = input_number.trim().parse().unwrap();
    let parsed_numb2: i32 = input_number2.trim().parse().unwrap();
    return operation(parsed_numb1, parsed_numb2);
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_string = String::new();
    println!("Enter either add, substract, multiply, or divide:");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string).unwrap();

    match input_string.as_str().trim() {
        "add" => {
            calc(add);
        }
        "subtract" => &calc(subtract), // error here 
        c => println!("Invalid command: {c}"),
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if im borrowing correctly, but it seems like its a borrow issue. How could it be flexible for other conditions like multiply, divide, and subtract.

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfcb0700972c9ac298294fed3f250242)

Comment: Did you mean to print out the result of the operation? Right now, you've got three match arms. One returns `i32`, one returns `&i32`, and the third returns `()`. What is the intended return type of the `match`? (I'm guessing `()` since you don't do anything with the result)

Comment: I guess so. I just want to be able to pass in the above functions to the calc function for certain string values, like add, substract, multiply, etc. That is what im trying to express in the code, but not sure what im doing wrong. They all return `i32` on the functions. Maybe &calc isn't ideal. I updated the code so it makes some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at just the match arms, and see which one has the

```rust
"add" => {
    calc(add);
}
```

The semicolon results in this arm returning the unit type `()`.

```rust
"subtract" => &calc(subtract), // error here
```

This arm returns a reference to the result of the calculation, `&i32`.

```rust
c => println!("Invalid command: {c}"),
```

`println!` returns the unit type as well, so this arm returns the unit type `()`.

So you have two arms that result in `()`, and one arm that doesn't. To correct that, you have two options:

1. Make all arms return `()` by adding a semicolon after the second `calc`:

```rust
    match input_string.as_str().trim() {
        "add" => {
            calc(add);
        }
        "subtract" => {
            calc(subtract);
        }
        c => println!("Invalid command: {c}"),
    }
```

2. Make the first two arms return `i32` and the last arm diverge by panicking instead of just printing:

```rust
    match input_string.as_str().trim() {
        "add" => calc(add),
        "subtract" => calc(subtract), 
        c => panic!("Invalid command: {c}"),
    }
```

Comment: thanks appreciate the answer, it seems that i had a typo that i didn't realize. The answer provides more clarity. I was blending javascript syntax with rust.

Answer (score 1):

`match`, in Rust, is an expression just like `1 + 1` or `calc()`. In fact, most things in Rust are expressions, and that means they return a value. In the case of `match`, all of its arms must return a value of the same type.

```
match input_string.as_str().trim() {
  "add" => {
    calc(add);
  }
  "subtract" => &calc(subtract), // error here 
  c => println!("Invalid command: {c}"),
}
```

In your current code, the `"add"` branch *would* return `i32` (the result of `calc`), but you suppress this with a semicolon to get `()`, pronounced "unit" The third branch returns the result of `println!`, which is also `()`.

The second arm returns the borrowed result of `calc`, so `&i32`. Which is not compatible with `()`.

Since you don't do anything with this result, I'm assuming you intended to print in each case. So something like

```
match input_string.as_str().trim() {
  "add" => {
    println!("{}", calc(add));
  }
  "subtract" => {
    println!("{}", calc(subtract));
  }
  c => {
    println!("Invalid command: {c}");
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish i could approve both answers, but i upvoted this one. Thank you for explaining.